# Is there a way to select a custom ROM for virtual machine in Virtual Box?

Tags: virtualbox, bios, uefi

Using [QEMU](http://www.qemu.org) it is straightforward to select different ROMs either as the main ROM or as a peripheral ROM (i.e. video or network card). Is there equivalent functionality in VirtualBox?

I am aware of the EFI check box, which selects OVMF, but I wish to try different versions of OVMF or coreboot without recompiling VirtualBox (so that the other virtual machines can keep running).

I know that I will not be able to do this from the GUI, but as the GUI is frequently used, I would need to be aware of any issues.

Comment: That is one Thing on my todo list, I also want to replace the pcbios nic rom with ipxe, and get efi pxe working, all of which require changes to various roms.

Comment: I've been researching this myself, and have not found much. Maybe time to try QEMU port on my laptop?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that there is an official feature request at https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/1929 - one commenter suggests a way to accomplish but it's not clear whether it works with the current version.

In addition, there's a request to patching Virtualbox's source to run coreboot at https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=817260 with no indication that it will happen.